# __FILE__ not giving complete file path in 64 bit configuration

Tags: c++

`__FILE__` is returning me the complete file path when I run the program in 32 bit.
But in 64 bit it is giving only the file name. How to resolve this?

Comment: Which compiler? Can you give us a simple example that demonstrates this? You could compile and run `int main() { printf("%s\n",__FILE__); }` and run it through your c++ compiler please?

Answer (score 3):

That depends probably more on the way you drive your compiler than a 32/64 bits difference.

My expectation (and what I verified just here with gcc) is that `__FILE__` gives the name as provided to the compiler.  For instance

```
$ cat foo.c
int main() { printf("%s\n",__FILE__); }
$ gcc foo.c & ./a.out
foo.c
$ gcc ./foo.c & ./a.out
./foo.c
$ gcc `pwd`/foo.c & ./a.out
/the/full/path/as/reported/by/pwd/foo.c
```

similarly for include files, the path reported is the one used by the compiler to access the header, thus may depend on the way you specified the include directories.